# Current Window Content cannot be identified anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, contentcontrol

I have programmed code on top of the MainWindow content.
As I added a login-mask to start before the MainWindow my programmed content distribution does not work properly anymore.

The code when the MainWindow is called and the login-mask is closed:

**Login-Mask Window Code (after successful login)**

```
MainWindow popup = new MainWindow();
popup.Show();
this.Close();
```

Within the MainWindow I am calling my content like this which still works when the MainWindow was called:

**MainWindow Content Code**

```
this.contentControl.Content = new UserControlXYZ();
```

Now when I call another UserControl from the new loaded contentControl.Content I get a NullPointerException (Before adding the login-mask it was loaded):

**UserControlXYZ Content Code**

```
 (Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("contentControl") as ContentControl).Content = new UserControlNEWControl();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appication **main window** gets set to the window which **is the start up window for an application**. So, in your case it will be Login window and since you have closed it, **`Application.Current.MainWindow`** will return null.

In case you want to get MainWindow, you can get it from **`Windows collection`** like this:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().First();
mainWindow.contentControl.Content = new UserControlNEWControl();
```

To use **`OfType<T>() and First()`** extension methods, add **`System.Linq`** namespace in your class.

Comment: Great and helpful answer!